# Is it safe to unbind a buffer that is mapped from glBufferStorage after mapping with GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT, and then write to the pointer?

Tags: opengl

I've been going through online blogs, reading up about [glMapNamedBufferRange](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMapBufferRange.xhtml)  and [glUnmapBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUnmapBuffer.xhtml), though the docs seem to only mention:

> If a mapping is not unmapped before the corresponding buffer object's data store is used by the GL, an error will be generated by any GL command that attempts to dereference the buffer object's data store, unless the buffer was successfully mapped with GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT (see glMapBufferRange).

and

> GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT ... It is not an error to call drawing commands (render) while buffers are mapped using this flag.

What I am trying to do is bind the entire range, hold onto the pointer, and update it as I go (it will also have `GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT` set) even after I unbind it. Problem is all the examples I find online are simple examples that just leave the buffer bound forever and then clean up at the end.

An example of what I'd like to do:

```
// I'll use this to explicitly show holding onto state for all of the following in the pseudocode

flags = GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT | GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT;

MyClass() {
    glGenBuffers(...);
    glBindBuffer(...);
    glBufferStorage(..., flags);
    this.data = glMapBufferRange(..., flags);
    glBindBuffer(..., 0);
}

~MyClass() {
    glBindBuffer(...);
    glUnmapBuffer(...);
    glBindBuffer(..., 0);

    glDeleteBuffers(...)
}

void update(int index, Stuff stuff) {
    // It's okay if it's not bound, correct?
    // This will do exactly what I want, which is update the buffer
    // with new data even if it's not bound, and it will get the data
    // to where it needs to be correctly because it's also coherent.
    this.data[index] = stuff;
}
```

This would be used for SSBOs that are accessed in the vertex and fragment shader.

In short, is the above is safe to do? I'm able to keep the pointer around even after unbinding and write to it as if it were bound? One blog post seems to imply I can do this but again... the example just binds everything and leaves it bound and I'm worried I've misread something and going to wander into some undefined behavior (or some GL error if I'm lucky).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In short, is the above is safe to do?

Yes. It is even safe to do with non-persistently mapped buffers. Until the buffer is not explicitely unmapped by you, the pointer is valid and it is safe to access the memory (only in ways consistent with the `access` flags, of course). That also means you can have multiple buffers mapped at the same time, of course (and you can do that via all the same buffer binding target).

The binding is just needed to tell the GL which buffer the `glMapBuffer[Range]()` is supposed to operate on, since that is OpenGL's default "bind-to-modify" programming paradigm. Note that with OpenGL 4.5, we have *direct state access*, and the DSA variants `glMapNamedBuffer[Range]` do not require you to bind a buffer just for mapping it in the first place.

> In short, is the above is safe to do?

As a totally unrelated side note: You should be careful with wrapping GL objects in C++ classes in the way you do, with `glGen...` in the constructor and `glDelete...` in the destructor. A common mistake is to create temproary objects of these kind, and assign them to some final variable, which will transfer the GL object name via the default copy constructor, but when the temporary is destroyed, the actual GL object by that name will be gone.